# Restriction on several elements of a complex type

Tags: xsd, restriction, complextype, xsd-1.0

I've a XML Schema with several elements, which each has two child elements of the same type (oldValue & newValue).
The type can for example be a string, but I've several elements with different `maxLength` restrictions. What's the easiest way to define this?

```
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element name="foo">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="oldValue" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="newValue">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="10"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xsd:element>

  <xsd:element name="bar">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="oldValue" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
      <xs:element name="newValue">
        <xs:simpleType>
          <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:maxLength value="30"/>
          </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
      </xs:element>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:sequence>
```

I need to define a lot of these elements, each with different restrictions. Is there an easier way than to define a complexe type for each restriction?

Edit: I need to use XML Schema 1.0

Answer (score 1):

If you can use XML Schema 1.1, the assert element allow you to add constraint to sub-structure. See http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema11-1/#cAssertions
The test attribute allows XPath 2.0 expressions.
For example :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" > 
    <xs:group name="valuesGroup">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="oldValue" type="xs:string"/>
            <xs:element name="newValue" type="xs:string"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:group>
    <xs:element name="root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="foo">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:group ref="valuesGroup"/>
                        <xs:assert test="every $x in * satisfies 
                            (string-length($x) &lt;= 30)"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="bar">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:group ref="valuesGroup"/>
                        <xs:assert test="every $x in * satisfies 
                            (string-length($x) &lt;= 10)"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>                
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>        
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Thanks, this would be the perfect solution, but unfortunately XML Schema 1.1 is no option